# Priority formula in excel or python pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, email, excel-formula

Let's say there are two columns in Excel:

```
A                B
tim@email.com  josh@email.com
math@email.com angel@email.com
nil@email.com  noemail
               jorme@email.com
```

I want to put a condition such as:

```
       A        B                   C
tim@email.com  josh@email.com  josh@email.com
math@email.com angel@email.com angel@email.com
nil@email.com  noemail         nil@email.com     
               jorme@email.com jorme@email.com
```

Setting priority to B and if not available any email at b then take from A.

Pandas and Excel formula both will be ok.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider that valid addresses in A contain a `@` character:

```
df['C'] = df['B'].where(df['B'].str.contains('@'), df['A'])

# or if you don't want to fill with potentially invalid addresses in B
# df['C'] = df['B'].where(df['B'].str.contains('@'),
#                         df['A'].where(df['A'].str.contains('@')))
```

Or testing if the value is not 'noemail':

```
df['C'] = df['B'].where(df['B'].ne('noemail'), df['A'])
```

output:

```
                A                B                C
0   tim@email.com   josh@email.com   josh@email.com
1  math@email.com  angel@email.com  angel@email.com
2   nil@email.com          noemail    nil@email.com
3                  jorme@email.com  jorme@email.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved desired result by using excel if conditions , See below

[image]

In column C, Paste below formula

```
=IF(B1="noemail",A1,B1)
```

Note :  you should mark "noemail" if no email id is present in column B .